# How to select class properties via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, css

This is the HTML in question:

```
<a href="#" class="a01">xxx a01</a>
<a href="#" class="b02">xxx a021</a>
<a href="#" class="c03">xxx aa021</a>
<a href="#" class="d04">xxx aaa2021</a>
```

On click on a link, jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function(){
   alert($(this).html()); // we get xxx a01 , xxx a021 and so on..
})
```

How do I get the class value, such as a01, b02, c03 and so on?

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use `this.className`, it's faster and less redundant than `$(this).attr("class")`.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    alert(this.className);
});
```

- [element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className) - Mozilla Developer Network

---

Most attributes are directly accessible as properties of the element, so wrapping jQuery around `this` and using `attr()` or `prop()` are generally unnecessary.

Read more on this at http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element (plug).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery's `.attr()` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) in order to retrieve any attribute from an element.

```
$(this).attr("class")
```

Comment: @dankypang: Once you've got answers that solve your problem, you may chose to select the best one as the "accepted answer" by clicking the grey checkmark beside it.

Comment: I'd use `.prop()` rather then `.attr()` for classname.

Comment: @RikudoSennin: I'm not sure I understand it, but I think that `.attr("class")` should be equivalent to `.prop("className")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($(this).attr('class'));
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/